# Separate by loose parts not working?

Tags: vertices, mirror, mirror-modifier

For some reason, trying to separate by loose parts in my project doesn't work. I can hit the button as many times as I want, but the pieces stay mirrored together. Specifically, I'm trying to separate the armor plates on the model (the forearm pieces, the shoulder, thighs, etc.). Is there something I'm missing? I've attached the .blend file below.

[image]

Comment: Did you uncheck "Merge" in the mirror modifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first apply the mirror modifier. Then TAB into edit mode, select all -> separate -> loose parts. Then it works.

[image]